After a few years away from school, inactive students may need to reapply for admission. Why?
At many schools in America, undergraduate students can freely take a semester or two off.  But some students might want to take a longer break:  perhaps two or three years.
At many schools, after multiple years of time off, a student must reapply for admission.  This may cost ~$100, and may require five or more pages of paperwork.  (Transcripts might not be needed, if the school still has them on file.)  Readmission is not guaranteed.  Why do many schools require this reapplication for admission?
I think the reapplication might be a waste of resources, for both the student and the school.
Also, the student may be busy with work, family responsibilities, and/or mental-health issues.  The reapplication requirement may discourage the student's return.  It may increase the unfortunate chance that the student will never graduate.  This, in turn, might also decrease the school's graduation rate statistics.

In theory, the application fee covers the cost to the university of processing that application, in terms of staff time and other expenses.  So by requiring a fee, there isn't any net waste of time or money to the admissions office; there may even be a profit.

that Q is very open-ended. Is there a real practical problem you are trying to solve?

"Why do many schools require this reapplication for admission?"
Because the student has already demonstrated they are unreliable so their suitability needs to be reassessed with that information in hand.

@aaaaasaysreinstateMonica:  I've added a postscript to the question, to explain.

Related but not directly - a danger of slowing taking classes again is that some schools require all your credits to be accomplished within a limited time window. (I don't know U Alberta's current rules but when I attended it was seven years) If they're planning on carrying past work forward make sure it doesn't "expire" before they graduate!

"Reapplying", at least in my school, is an administrative process that doesn't involve the admissions office or process.  It just means that they're doing due diligence I gence about whether whatever took you out of school has been resolved.


To encourage students not to drop out in the first place by adding a barrier to that path. You're right, schools are ranked in part on having a path to successful graduation, but the university likely sees it as more important to retain the students they have than to facilitate returning, because they know the chances of people returning once they quit are quite low.

The size of the student body has some practical limitations on it. If a student drops out and then decides to come back, they need a "slot" again. It may seem like a burden on the student to make them reapply, but it would be similarly unfair to another student who applied and would have been accepted except for this returning student who took their spot and has since shown themselves to be a bit less reliable as a student on account of having dropped out once. Reapplying gives the university a new chance to evaluate whether they think the student is likely to complete their studies over another student they'd enroll instead.

Because there are administrative costs to this student's actions, and application fees are a way for the university to pay their administrative costs and discourage a student from opting to return, registering for classes, and then dropping out before tuition is due. Requiring an application fee forces the student to buy-in a bit and show that their interest in continuing is at least worth a fee that is quite small in relation to the overall time commitment of an undergraduate program.



To encourage students not to drop out in the first place by adding a barrier to that path. - Is this really part of administrators' logic behind this rule?  I would guess that most students wouldn't even think about/be aware of this before being on leave for several semesters already.  (Your reasons 2 and 3 sound much more compelling to me.)

@Kimball I think Nate Eldredge's answer provides an additional bit of detail; they want to have as many students graduate within 6 years as possible, fewer is even better. I'd expect an institution to be proactive in giving notice to withdrawing students and those who have been gone a year that they must re-enroll now or else pay fees and reapply. I don't know how effective that pressure is but it's more than nothing and might be the encouragement some students need to finish now rather than putting it off.

The large public university in my area has an opt-in program that encourages students to graduate in 4 years, which was the customary duration of an undergraduate degree -- yes, even in engineering -- when I was a student 40 years ago.

It's possible that over the next few years you'll see many colleges, especially non-selective colleges, reduce barriers to returning. Colleges are competing for a declining number of prospective students (the size of each high school graduation cohort is shrinking each year and a lower percentage of HS grads are going to college) and are looking for ways to increase enrollment.

@shoover I don't understand what you mean. Graduation in 4 years is the expected timeline, so what are they opting into, exactly?

@AzorAhai-him- Over the years, so many students have not graduated in 4 years but have stretched that time to 5 years, 6 years, or never. That's why, as Bryan Krause alludes in his comment and as Nate Eldredge says in his answer, the 6-year graduation rate is measured.

@shoover I don't understand your reply. I asked about your statement "The large public university in my area has an opt-in program that encourages students to graduate in 4 years." But this is the default expectation, so what are they opting into, exactly?

@AzorAhai-him- I don't know where you're from, but the university I'm speaking of, which serves a large population of students who are non-wealthy, non-white, and/or the first in their family to attend college, has seen its 4-year graduation rate rise from about 18% to about 45% over the past 12 years, and its 6-year rate rise from 48% to about 65% for the same cohorts. Over the same period, the National Student Clearinghouse Research Center has measured and reported on the six-year completion rates for four-year schools... 1/3

...and the three-year completion rates for two-year schools. Recent reports have added the eight-year completion rates for four-year schools. The numbers in these reports show that the university I'm speaking of has a six-year graduation rate slightly below average for public four-year institutions. One of the sites that ranks colleges says, "Unless stated otherwise, 'graduation rate' refers to the percentage of college entrants who graduate from the first institute they attended within six years." 2/3

Even US News uses the six-year graduation rate. While the goal may be to graduate in 4 years, that's not the expectation by any means, nor is it across the board, which is why graduation rates are usually presented at the 6-year level. So what these students are opting into is a pledge to graduate from a four-year school in four years, which is no longer the norm, if it ever was. 3/3

@shoover. Thanks for the added details. From my perspective, 4 years remains very much the cultural and academic norm but this isn’t the space to go much further


This, in turn, might also decrease the school's graduation rate statistics.

Not really.  Graduation rate statistics are usually based on four-year, five-year, and six-year graduation rates; see for instance in the Common Data Set, items B4-B21.  Thus a student who graduates but takes more than six years to do so is equivalent, for statistical purposes, to one who never graduates at all.
As such, graduation rate statistics don't actually provide an incentive to readmit students who have taken significant time off, since they won't be able to graduate within six years of their initial enrollment and so cannot be a "credit" in those statistics.  On the contrary, this means universities have an incentive to discourage students from taking off for more than a year or two, and requiring such students to apply for readmission has this effect.

Interesting! What about part-time students, who take, say, eight or ten years to graduate? Do they simply push graduation rates down? Perhaps statisticians should collect data on both six-year and 20-year graduation rates.

@unforgettableidSupportsMonica: As explained in the CDS document, only full-time, degree-seeking students are to be counted in those statistics, so part-time students don't affect the rate at all.

(That is, students who started as full-time.  A student who starts as full time and then voluntarily switches to part time, taking more than six years to graduate, will pull the rate down.  A student who started as part time will not be counted at all.)
